# can't create a new table with spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After read the demo in [spring.io](http://spring.io)I try to write a demo for spring boot jpa of my own.But when I ran the demo it has these problem.It said **Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.example.model.Person**.And here is the detail. I had made some changes, but I still have this problem.

```
17:55:40.430 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
17:55:40.432 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
17:55:40.432 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/E:/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/demo/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-08-09 17:55:40.645  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on MoriatyC with PID 10472 (E:\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\demo\target\classes started by cmh in E:\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\demo)
2017-08-09 17:55:40.645  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-08-09 17:55:40.828  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@617bc958: startup date [Wed Aug 09 17:55:40 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-09 17:55:42.196  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-08-09 17:55:42.208  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-08-09 17:55:42.208  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2017-08-09 17:55:42.299  INFO 10472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-08-09 17:55:42.299  INFO 10472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1474 ms
2017-08-09 17:55:42.433  INFO 10472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-08-09 17:55:42.437  INFO 10472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-09 17:55:42.438  INFO 10472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-09 17:55:42.438  INFO 10472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-09 17:55:42.438  INFO 10472 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-09 17:55:42.884  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-08-09 17:55:42.898  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-08-09 17:55:42.950  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-08-09 17:55:42.951  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-08-09 17:55:42.952  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-08-09 17:55:43.045  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-08-09 17:55:43.126  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-08-09 17:55:43.259  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
2017-08-09 17:55:43.264  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-08-09 17:55:43.288  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-08-09 17:55:43.301  WARN 10472 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'searchController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.dao.PersonRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-08-09 17:55:43.302  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-08-09 17:55:43.307  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-08-09 17:55:43.317  INFO 10472 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-09 17:55:43.414 ERROR 10472 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field personRepository in com.example.controller.SearchController required a bean of type 'com.example.dao.PersonRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.dao.PersonRepository' in your configuration.
```

And here is the **PersonRepository.java**

```
package com.example.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

import com.example.model.Person;

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Integer> {
    List<Person> findByAddress(String address);
    Person findByNameAndAddress(String name, String address);
    @Query("select p from Person p where p.name = :name and p.address=:address")
    Person withNameAndAddressQuery(@Param("name")String name, @Param("address")String address);
    Person withNameAndAddressNamedQuery(String name, String address);
}
```

**Person.java**

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity 
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NamedQuery(name="Person.withNameAndAddressNamedQuery", query = "select p from Person p where p.name=?1 and p.address=?2")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String address;
}
```

**SearchController.java**

```
package com.example.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.dao.PersonRepository;
import com.example.model.Person;


@RestController
public class SearchController {
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/save")
    public Person save(String name, String address, Integer age) {
        Person p = personRepository.save(new Person(null, name, age, address));
        return p;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/q1")
    public List<Person> q1(String address) {
        List<Person> people = personRepository.findByAddress(address);
        return people;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/q2")
    public Person q2(String name, String address) {
        Person people = personRepository.findByNameAndAddress(name, address);
        return people;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/q3")
    public Person q3(String name, String address) {
        Person people = personRepository.withNameAndAddressQuery(name, address);
        return people;
    }
    public Person q4(String name, String address) {
        Person p = personRepository.withNameAndAddressNamedQuery(name, address);
        return p;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/sort")
    public List<Person> sort() {
        List<Person> people = personRepository.findAll(new Sort(Direction.ASC,"age"));
        return people;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/page")
    public Page<Person> page() {
       Page<Person> pagePeople = personRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(1, 2));
       return pagePeople;
    }
}
```

Here is the **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...) -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Use MySQL Connector-J -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.10</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.22</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>18.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and this is the **application.properties**

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jackson.serialization.indent-output=true
```

Here is my **Application.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example") . as spring boot has the the ability to auto scan your component. also auto scan will work if your components/configs are in sub-package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no problem with your code, the problem is the hierarchy of your project, the Application class should be in a parent level to your model, so it can scan your model, please check your files.

or you can add `@SpringBootApplication` like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example.model"})
   public class Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

Comment: I updated the **PersonRepository.java** ,but **console log** still have the problem like before.

Comment: Can you run the demo well? I changed the **Person.java**, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I remove it, and write a new Constructor that have all the args, it still doesn't work. @AllArgsConstructor just create a Constructor that includes all args automatically. I don't think it will cause the problem.

Comment: thats strange, it works with me! can you please share your main class code?

Comment: please check my answer now

Comment: I have added my application.java above, at first I have @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.dao") at my application.java, after I deleted that, the console changed. Its strange, I do scan the repository.

Comment: see? the path in your application `package com.example.demo` but in your model `package com.example.model` // try to move your application a level up physically and change package to `package com.example;`